# Comparar varias columnas de un df con una columna de otro

Tags: r, tidyverse

Necesito comparar diversas columnas de un data frame con una columna de otro y que me devuelva, para cada columna del 1er df un valor si cumple la condición y otro si no la cumple.

```
df1
id   col1   col2
id1  val1   val1
id2  val1   val2
id3  val2   val2
id4  val2   val1

df2
id   col1
id1  val1
id2  val2
id3  val2
id4  val1

df_resultado
id   col1   col2
id1  ok     ok
id2  mal    ok
id3  ok     ok
id4  mal    ok
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es bastante simple, comparamos directamente `df1` con `df2.col1`:

```
# Quitamos el id de la comparación
ifelse(df1[,-1] == df2$col1, "Ok", "Mal")

     col1  col2
[1,] "Ok"  "Ok"
[2,] "Mal" "Ok"
[3,] "Ok"  "Ok"
[4,] "Mal" "Ok"
```